# restoring old submit function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit

u have a form with input data. like

```
<form id = 'myform'>
...
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="supplier_aid" value="on" checked disabled >{$output.t_artikelnr}</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="descshort" value="on">{$output.t_kurztext}</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="buyer_aid" value="on">{$output.t_sap_materialnr}</td>
...
</form>
```

on document ready i replace the default submit function with my function (only way, legacy code strikes again...)

```
document.myform.submit = function (){
 //do some stuff..

//and eventually

return true;
}
```

but now no form submit happens... anyone knows how can i restore the submit behavior?

here is the whole js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){


        document.articlelistform.progress = {};     
        document.articlelistform.progress.update = function(){
            var variables = document.articlelistform.progress;
            var state = variables.data.done / variables.data.togo;    
            if(document.articlelistform.progress.lock){
                 variables.bar.updateProgress(state,'{/literal}{$output.m_queue_progress_message_status}{literal}')
                 return;
            }


            if(typeof(variables.togo) =='undefined'){
                variables.togo = 5;
                }
            switch(variables.data.state){
                case 'inQue':

                        variables.bar.updateProgress((5 - variables.togo) / 5,'{/literal}{$output.m_queue_progress_message_gathering}{literal}');   
                        variables.togo--;
                        if(variables.togo <= 0) variables.togo = 5;
                        document.articlelistform.submit(variables.data);

                    break;
                case 'inProcess':
                    if(variables.togo <= 0 || variables.data.update){
                        variables.togo = 5;
                        variables.bar.updateProgress(state,'{/literal}{$output.m_queue_progress_message_genarating}{literal} '+ variables.data.done + '/' + variables.data.togo);   
                        document.articlelistform.submit(variables.data);

                    }else variables.togo--;

                    break;
                case 'downloadDone': 
                        variables.bar.updateProgress(1,'{/literal}{$output.m_queue_progress_message_download}{literal}!');   
                            if(window.location != 'failed'){
                                window.location = variables.data.location;
                                clearInterval(variables.ticking);
                                delete variables.ticking;
                                variables.togo = 5;
                                variables.state = 'new';
                            }else{
                                document.articlelistform.progress.bar.updateProgress(1,'{/literal}{$output.m_queue_progress_message_networkerr}{literal}!');
                            }
                       break;
                 case 'error' :
                     clearInterval(variables.ticking);
                     delete variables.ticking;
                     variables.togo = 5;
                     variables.state = 'error';
                     document.articlelistform.progress.bar.updateProgress(1,'{/literal}{$output.m_queue_progress_message_server_error}{literal}');
                     document.articlelistform.submit(variables.data);
                     break;

            }
        }

        document.articlelistform.submit = function(data){
            var settings = document.articlelistform.progress;
            settings.lock  = true;

            if(typeof(data) == 'undefined') data = {state:'new'};

            if(typeof(settings.data) != 'undefined')
            if(settings.data.state == 'downloadDone'){
               window.location = settings.data.location; 
               return false;
            }
            if(typeof(data) == 'object')
                if(data.state == 'error') document.articlelistform.submit()

            $('#formSettings').val(JSON.stringify(data));       
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'ajax-backend/downloadCatalogueProgress.php',
                data:   $(this).serialize() ,

                success: function(data){

                    settings.lock  = false;
                    if(!data.error){

                        if((data.state == 'inQue' && typeof(settings.bar) == 'undefined')||data.progress){
                            delete data.progress;
                            $('#catalogMessageHolder').html('');
                            settings.bar = new Ext.ProgressBar({
                                renderTo: 'catalogMessageHolder',
                                value: 0.1,
                                width: 200,
                                maxValue:60,
                                minValue: 0,
                                text : '{/literal}{$output.m_queue_progress_message_genarating}{literal}.'

                            });
                            settings.data  = data;     
                            document.articlelistform.progress.ticking  = setInterval(settings.update, 1000, data, true);
                        }else{
                            settings.data  = data;
                        }
                        $('#cataloLoaderHolder').show();

                    }else{
                    //@todo: implement a warning message
                    }

                },
                failure: function(){
                 document.articlelistform.progress.bar.updateProgress(1,'{/literal}{$output.m_queue_progress_message_networkerr}{literal}!');
                } 
            });

            return true; 
        };
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Are you saying `$('#myForm').on('submit', function() { ... });` does'nt work ?

Comment: Not in this case becouse the submit is trigered from an on click function call.

Comment: So what -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/x4P7H/) ??? You're going about this all wrong. You're using native elements and native submit functions when you're already using jQuery, which really screws thing up for you. If you used `$(document.articlelistform).submit();` you would trigger the submit and just cach it with `.on('submit')` instead of messing around with redeclaring native ECMA methods!

Comment: Trust me i would change it if i could... but i am not permited to touch the god damn submit button..

Comment: Could'nt you just remove the onclick function with jQuery, or is'nt that an option either. Otherwise you're screwed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get permission from my supervisor to change the god damn thing.

And i get why he dint want me to change it... it is hard-coded in like 20 places.... changed all.
 Just changed the js call with jquery call and all worked as it should. No idea why it dint work earlier. but this is the on click which called the function

```
> <td class="blue" background="gfx/buttonb.gif" align="center"
> valign="center"><nobr><a  href="javascript:void(0)" class="blue"
> onclick="if (!(document.articlelistform.catalogpartner3200.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner3582.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner5320.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner5109.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner4774.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner3271.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner3526.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner5544.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner3494.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner3416.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner4439.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner5328.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner5329.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner3267.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner3512.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner2848.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner3417.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner3491.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner3492.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner5554.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner5591.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner5611.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner3517.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner5305.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner3532.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner5077.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner3581.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner3507.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner3579.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner3489.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner3490.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner5306.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner5598.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner5191.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner3305.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner3578.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner3580.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner4934.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner4437.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner3568.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner4079.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner3723.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner5321.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.catalogpartner3569.checked)) {alert('Sie
> müssen mind. 1 Katalog auswählen');  } else { if
> (!(document.articlelistform.supplier_aid.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.descshort.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.buyer_aid.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.desclong.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.keywords.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.manufacturer_name.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.delivery_time.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.remarks.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.reference_feature_group_id.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.order_unit.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.content_unit.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.quantity_min.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.quantity_interval.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.price_amount.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.special_treatment_class.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.mimeinfo.checked ||
> document.articlelistform.sicherheitsdatenblatt.checked )) {alert('Sie
> müssen mind. 1 Auswahlkriterium wählen!');  } else {
> $('#catalogDownloadForm').submit(); } } return false;" onMouseOver=
> "window.status='Als CSV-Datei downloaden'; return true;"
> onMouseOut="window.status=''; return true;">&nbsp;Als CSV-Datei
> downloaden&nbsp;</a></td>
```

the code is nuts.... i just changed from `document.articlelistform.submit()` to  `$('#catalogDownloadForm').submit()` and all worked like it should.. no idea why it fails otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.myform.submit = function (event) {
    // init event if undefined
    if (!event) var event = window.event;
    if (doNotSubmit) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // form won't be submitted
    } else {
        // will automatically submit, no need to return anything
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Obviously, you're using jQuery. Then, another solution could work:

```js
$("#myForm").on("submit", function() {
    if (doNotSubmit) {
        return false;
        // form won't be submitted
    } else {
        return true;
        // form will be submitted
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry that is not working, because im calling the submit function from js. and  then the default handler duos not get passed.

Comment: @Sangoku See my edit (from [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html), section *Cross-browser event accessing*).

Comment: @Sangoku Since you seem to use jQuery, you could use its event handling (see my re-edit).

Comment: tried with jquery, the submit() function dous not triger on this form becoue some idiot used <submit onclick='document.myform.submit()'>

Comment: here is an example of the code which ilustrates mu problem with submit http://jsfiddle.net/StCPp/4/

Comment: @Sangoku Either use `onclick='document.myform.submit(event)'` if you're allowed, since the event will be automatically bound, or use the `if (!event) var event = window.event;` line I added in my first edit. Both worked for me on your jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared an onsubmit event handler, you've redeclared submit itself!!!

So either, you really wanted to do:

```
document.myform.onsubmit = function(){
  // do some stuff...
  // and eventually
  return true;
};
```

Looks like you did, otherwise there would be no need to return anything, because `document.myform.submit` doesn't.

If this is deliberate (eek!), before you redefine `document.myform.submit` you need to store it:

```
document.myform.originalSubmit = document.myform.submit;
document.myform.submit = function (){
  //do some stuff..
  //and eventually
  document.myform.originalSubmit();
};
```

Since this bypasses any event handlers you have associated with your form, I don't see how that's what you really want, as it's not going to play nicely with other code.

Comment: sadly i was forced to redeclare it.. the even handler wont cach it otherwise... i tried to store it, but then i get acess denied when i try to trigger it.

Comment: I think that's been fixed.  Since it's working in Firefox 17, IE, Opera, Safari & Chrome.

Comment: @Sangoku "sadly i was forced to redeclare it.. the even handler wont cach it otherwise"  I don't understand this.  Event handlers don't fire when you call a form's submit() function in JavaScript.  They only fire when the user submits the form via the browser UI.

Comment: Actually, it looks like that message you're getting is a result of other things in your code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039577/using-jquery-validate-to-upload-a-form-using-ajax-in-the-submithandler-not

Comment: That is the message from fb. he message in chrome says unhallowed access.

Comment: Huh?  I did what my answer said, with your JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/StCPp/6/ - It works.  I think you must have a different problem.  Perhaps the line number of the error message will help you determine what is really happening.